# Why do my powershell code behaviors differently when called from another file as a module?

Tags: json, powershell

I wrote a powershell function to automatically merge .json files. It's quite simple. In summary:

1. It receives three paths. The first for the old file, the second for the new file, the third for target.
2. It will iterate over all leaves of the json tree of the new file and generate a list containing an unique address for each single leaf.
3. It will iterate over the list of addresses and: if that address exists in the new and old json, the value of this address in the new json will be the same as the old json. If the value exists in the new json and does not exists in the old json, the address and the value are preserved in the new json. If the address exists in the old json and does not exists in the new json, it will continue not existing in the new json.
4. The resultant new json will be saved in the target path.

I wrote this code as a part of a project in which I'm writting this kind of simple auto merger for some file types like .ini and .xml. I wrote all the merger functions as powershell modules (.psm1) and then I call them from a .ps1 file that makes the interface between the user and the merge scripts.

The issue I'm having is the following. When I test the json merger as a .ps1 file it works flawless.
Example running it as .ps1:

JsonMerge.ps1

```
function MergeJsonFiles($oldCfgPath, $newCfgPath, $targetCfgPath) {
    # CODE
    $json | Out-File -FilePath "$targetCfgPath"
}

MergeJsonFiles './oldtest.json' './newtest.json' './targettest.json'
```

oldtest.json

```json
{
  "A": {
    "B": [
      {
        "ABC": 1,
        "DEF": 2
      },
      {
        "A$C": "AB$CE",
        "ASDC": "ASDHJ"
      }
    ]
  },
  "D": "Deprecated Value"
}
```

newtest.json

```json
{
  "A": {
    "B" : [
      {
        "ABC": 0,
        "DEF": 0
      },
      {
        "A$C": "A",
        "ASDC": "A"
      }
    ]
  },
  "N": "New Value"
}
```

Result: targettest.json

```json
{
  "A": {
    "B": [
      {
        "ABC": 1,
        "DEF": 2
      },
      {
        "A$C": "AB$CE",
        "ASDC": "ASDHJ"
      }
    ]
  },
  "N": "New Value"
}
```

But this is what happnes when I call the same function, with the same arguments but importing it as a module:
The old and new test files are the same, but this is the resultant target json

```json
{
  "A": {
    "B": [
      {
        "ABC": "1$",
        "DEF": "2$"
      },
      {
        "A$C": "A",
        "ASDC": "ASDHJ$",
        "A": "AB$"
      }
    ]
  },
  "N": "New Value"
}
```

Why does it happens? Why there is an "$" in the end of each value? Why does the numeric values became strings ended with "$"? I simply don't understand.
All code is on [github](https://github.com/estevaopbs/ConfigMerge/tree/main). Please help.

### EDIT

I find out that the issue was happening due to the fact I was running the code within WSL using the powershell installation of the linux system. As my vscode is set for linux and I don't want to have to set it for windows I use it to make and test my powershell scripts. When running it on windows it worked fine. I don't know if it is an misbehavior of the linux build of powershell or just an issue with my environment. When I ran the code directly on windows powershell it worked as expected.

Comment: Can you show a full code sample of how you are “importing it as a module”?

Comment: @mclayton in my github project it is being imported as a module. I changed the extension of the file to .psm1 and then I do the following in the main file: Import-Module "./XmlMerge/XmlMerge.psm1"           MergeXmlFiles $OldFile $NewFile $TargetPath

Comment: I haven't tried to fully understand your code but I strongly suspect your use of `Invoke-Expression` to be the root of the problem. Apart from `Invoke-Expression` generally be regarded as insecure, you may run into all kind of escaping issues (what if strings in the JSON contain `'` for instance). Your problem will likely go away if you replace the `Invoke-Expression` code by regular PowerShell code.

Comment: Comments in general about your code - there are much better examples on stackoverflow already if you search for "powershell merge hashtable" - yours has a couple of issues: (i) it doesn't handle bools - e.g. ```"abc" = true``` gives ```True: The term 'True' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet```", and there's a gaping injection attack due to use of ```Invoke-Expression``` - for example a json document containing ```"ABC": "'; write-host 'aaa",``` will *execute* the ```write-host``` command. Now imagine if the json document contained ```"ABC": "'; Format-Volume -DriveLetter 'C``` :-S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was different PowerShell environments in WSL and Windows. I deleted my previous answer, since @mklement0 pointed out that neither of my two recommended solutions make that much sense once you look deeper into it. Cannot delete this answer, since it has been marked as accepted.

Comment: It's not impossible since my dev environment runs within wsl. I have three installations of powershell in my machine: PS 5.1, which comes from windows installation; PS 7.3, that I installed; and PS 7.3 too but installed in wsl. I'll check whether this behavior persists when running everything on directly on windows.

Comment: Yeah the different PowerShell versions where just an idea, since you mentioned it behaves differently when executing it as a module. It's weird... You could print out the current PowerShell version at the top of your function with the `Get-Host` cmdlet to see if there are any differences. Did playing around with the `-Depth` and the `-Compress` parameter solve any of your issues?

Comment: Right in the bull's-eye. When I ran the script directly on windows everything worked as expected.

Comment: @sbb, when you run it directly on Windows as opposed to running it how? If there are two different methods of invoking the code involved (aside from running via a module vs. a `.ps1` script), please include this information in your question. As presented, your symptom is a mystery, and both your question and the acceptance of this answer are likely to confuse future readers.

Comment: Makes sense, I did not look as deep into the individual commands and just checked his github code quickly. I deleted my previous answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating, @dan-kli; given the circumstances, that's probably the best solution (though running the code in a WSL PowerShell instance vs. a Windows instance alone also doesn't explain the difference).

Comment: Sry, I'll add an edit to my post to make things more clear. I've been very busy, but I'll do it soon.